# ClickHouse difference between role GRANT and SET

Tags: clickhouse

question post to StackExchange;
Please help my study for Role assignment. ClickHouse is using two methods of Role assignment;

1. GRANT
2. SET

eg 1: GRANT admin TO user1
eg 2: SET ROLE admin TO user1

I can't find difference of these two. Please advice if you have any knlowledge of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is two different commands:

- [GRANT](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/grant/) assigns a role to user accounts not *apply / activate* it
- [SET ROLE](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/set-role/) activates role to the **current** user so that role be used

Example (see https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/role/#create-role-examples):

```sql
CREATE ROLE accountant;
GRANT SELECT ON db.* TO accountant;

GRANT accountant TO user1;
```

```sql
/* login as user1 */

/* activate the role and use related privileges */
SET ROLE accountant;
SELECT * FROM db.*;
```

To avoid calling *SET ROLE* each time after user login it needs to add role to the default list by [SET DEFAULT ROLE](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/set-role/#set-default-role-statement).

Comment: Thanks! I think I don't need to run SET statement if role assigned to user as Default role.